# Cloud Functions Locations - London

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am based in the UK and starting a new project. I would like to use London (europe-west2) for my Cloud Firestore location.

In the [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations) it explicitly states that Cloud functions are available in London. However, when I go to create my project I get a warning saying that could functions are not yet available in this location.

Which is correct??

[image: Firebase setup]

Comment: Oops! I'll send this to the Firebase UI team

Comment: I've created an internal issue ticket for this, reference b/132064260 with support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions is definitely available in London, we've just been slightly behind updating this warning on the Firebase UI. Here's a screenshot of creating a Cloud Function via the GCP console:

[image: Screenshot showing europe-west2 as the creation region for a Cloud Function]

Comment: Ok great. Thanks